# How to do nested comments where 1st level is sort desc, and 2nd level is sort asc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, nested

I'm using rails and awesome_nested_set to create nested_comments (artists have many sketchbook_comments).  I would like to have the 1st level be sort desc by timestamp so that we can see the newest comments at the top, above the fold.  I would like comments of comments to be in ASC chronological order of timestamp so that we can follow the conversations in order that they were created.  Like stack overflow I plan to only have just 1 level of nesting for now.

```
 #controller
def create

 #create 1st level comment as simple association
 @sketchbook_comment = @artist.sketchbook_comments.create(params[:sketchbook_comment])

 #if replying to a comment, only then do we nest
 if parent = @artist.sketchbook_comments.where(:id => params[:parent_id]).first
   @sketchbook_comment.move_to_child_of(parent)
 end

  redirect_to :back
end
```

I'm able to get all the comments for an association in one DB call:

```
artist.sketchbook_comments.order("lft ASC")
```

But it seems that all new root level comments are put at the "end" or "right side" of the tree (have a larger lft value then any previous nodes).  Therefore sorting by lft dooms me to only chronological order everywhere.

Any suggestions?  (I know I can achieve this by fetching all the root nodes order("created_at DESC"), then run comment.children.order("lft ASC") at each level, but I prefer not to hit the DB multiple times if possible.)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up added a model method that would use awesome_nested_set's move_to_left_of(id) in order to position new nodes on left when inserting root level comments.